# Does "at least one Y" properly introduce an Y if used for for the first time as well as "a" or "an" does?

Tags: claim-construction

The invention is a tool that has a least one of feature Y on a first location. 
Then in preferred embodiments have feature Y in a second location and also different possible configurations and numbers of Y on the tool.

My question is how do I introduce Y correctly and still have it make sense with the dependent wording? I find many articles I read say you must `preferably` use "a" or "an" to introduce an element. What is the best most clear way to make an examiner happy?

Example 1:
Independent claim: Tool, comprising: X with a first location and a second location; and *at least one* Y on the first location.

Dependent claim: The tool defined in claim 1, wherein at least one said Y is also located on the second location.

Example 2:
Independent claim: Tool, comprising: X with a first location, and a second location; and *`a`* Y on the first location.

Dependent claim: The tool defined in claim 1, wherein at least one said Y is also located on the second location.

Example 3: Or should I say: at least one of `a` Y? That way there is the proverbial `a`, or does that even matter or help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each of the two locations can only have a single location, you do not want to say there is at least one Y in location one. Example 2 is better. Also, the independent claim does not need to set the stage for the dependent claim by reciting a second location. It could be seen as narrowing claim. Looking at an an infringer that had one Y at some location a jury might say "I do not see that it has any such thing as a 'second location' so it doesn't have all elements."

Without the second Y somewhere, 'second location' as a placeholder in the independent claim is not needed and potentially harmful. Just bring in the second location in the dependent claim.

Comment: The locations I mentioned  features of element X, first side, second side, distal tip end, proximal end and the like. In Landis on Mechanics of Patent Claim Drafting "Parts or features of elements: Where relevant to functionality, the features of an element (the size, shape, geometry, construction material, constituent parts, apertures, orientation, etc.) should be mentioned"

Comment: My main concern was using "at least one of" instead of "a". I know "a" after comprising can be construed as possibly plural, but I was trying to being more clear. Alas.

Comment: Do you want to allow for more than one Y per "location" or not?

Comment: Yes sir. There can be more than one Y per location area. X has two sides. Y can be anywhere on one of two main sides of X; which side does not matter, but at least one. Having multiple Y on both sides and at more specific locations on each side, such as toward the tip or toward the bottom of each side, adds utility.  I plan to add that extra utility in the dependent claims.

Comment: I do not think my question was clear. For example, could there be two Y's one a first side, at the tip? To me, that is an example of "a" location.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you are saying. I know I'm having difficulty clarifying this in claim language. 
X is a special blade that has two sides.
Y is a special pattern mark.
at least one Y must be somewhere on one of the two sides of X
It's better if a Y is on both sides of X.
It's also better if a Y is close to the tip and close to the proximal end of X. 
It's also better if some Y's are at different angles slopes. Multiple Y's in multiple locations, on both sides, and at different angle slopes all on the two sides of X is best of all.

Comment: In that case  - you have "a" Y at a first location in the independent claim. If that + other characteristics is not enough for patentablity you might need include "and a second Y at a second location" or specify the location of the single Y to achieve novelty and non-obviousness.